# First Drag-Drop operation in PyQt application is very slow

Tags: performance, drag-and-drop, pyqt, delay

I have a very basic PyQt application (Qt 4.8) that allows me to drag an item from a QListWidget to another QListWidget. The GUI was developed in Qt Designer for convenience. The problem I'm seeing is when I try to drag an item for the first time, it seems to take 5 to 10 seconds for the application to recognize that I'm trying to drag something.

For subsequent drag events, the drag happens pretty much instantaneously.

I have experimented with other widgets (QTreeWidget, QTableWidget etc.) and they all show the same type of initial delay.

I have changed QApplication.startDragDistance and QApplication.startDragTime but it hasn't had any sort of beneficial effect.

Has anyone seen this before? Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it in the question?

Comment: And since this sounds like a bug, please state the *exact* versions of both PyQt and Qt, along with the platform.